# having done something

Tags: verbs

Can I use this in the future like this?

She, having painted the house,can invite to the friends

Having done the task , she can go:

In advance,thanks to all of you

Comment: Migrate to ELL? ----------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first, fine apart from "can invite her friends (not to the friends)". The second is OK.